# What are the upsides of using dependency parsing over constituency parsing?

Tags: computational-linguistics, reference-request, parsing, dependency-grammar

I am looking for an exhaustive list of upsides of using dependency parsing over constituency parsing (if possible, with references for each upside).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [dependency parsing is often faster than constituency parsing](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/6875/2680).

Two more reasons:

*Kübler, Sandra, Ryan McDonald, and Joakim Nivre. "[Dependency parsing.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2357908457250641490&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)"Synthesis Lectures on Human Language Technologies 1.1 (2009): 1-127.*

> One reason for the increasing popularity is the fact that dependency-based syntactic representations seem to be useful in many applications of language technology, such as machine translation and information extraction, thanks to their transparent encoding of predicate-argument structure.
>
> [There is a ] perception that dependency grammar is better suited than phrase structure grammar for languages with free or flexible word order, making it possible to analyze typologically diverse languages within a common framework.